# Block input while JDialog is open

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, jdialog

I've a program that, when I open an image with JDialog, the consoles freezes, as expected, but if I write on the console while frozen, the scanner will catch what I typed, after I close the image, the scanner will give me what I typed earlier. I tried to reset the scanner but it didn't work.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("example.png");

        try{
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(file);
            ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
            JLabel lbl=new JLabel();
            lbl.setIcon(icon);
            
            JFrame frame=new JFrame();
            JDialog jdialog = new JDialog(frame, name, true);

            jdialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            jdialog.setSize(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            jdialog.setModal(true);
            jdialog.add(lbl);
            jdialog.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println("Current working directory : " + workingDir);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.print("Type something: ");
        String line = stdin.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You typed "+line+", right?");
    }
}
```

**What I wanted to do:**

(Show image)

User type: hello

(User closes image)

Type something:

User type: bye

You typed bye, right?

**What happens:**

(Show image)

User type: hello

(User closes image)

Type something: hello

You typed hello, right?

Comment: Don't use a Scanner. If you are building a graphical application then use a `JOptionPane` to get user input.

Comment: @camickr, I'm not doing a graphical application, I just use JDialog for a short amount of time, but I think I'll change everything to a graphical application and use JOptionPane as you suggested.

Anyways, I kept trying to solve my problem and I came out with this solution:
`stdin.skip(".*");`
`stdin = new Scanner("System.in");`
`System.out.print("Type something: ");`


It works, but I don't know how safe it is to do this...